# Designing MongoDB model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model

i have one conceptual question about designing data model in mongo db.
I have some record for "lists". Each list is "one row" record with id, descr, createdBy etc. fiels. But now i have a requirement that each "list" can be shared with other users. What is the best way to design/re-design the model so when user login to see "lists" that he created and "lists" that was shared with him? I was thinking of creating new field "sharedWith" in which all usernames with which "list" is shared to be put separated with comma(or something else). And then when request is made to search in this field. But somehow this approach doesn't seem to me very useful. Can you give me some advice or guidelines ?
I'm using nodejs with mongoose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User: {
  ...
  myLists: Array<ListObject>
  sharedLists: Array<ListObject>
};

ListObject: {
  ...
  owner: User,
  sharedWith: Array<User>
};
```

That would seem a sensible design to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raynos. But if change is made to ListObject that is shared with the user, how this change is made and in the sharedLists? Or just update it in both places? (sorry if the question is stupid but i'm kinda new to mongodb)

Comment: @countnazgul you update in both places. It's called denormalization. It's what you do with mongoDB because it gives you speed